# how to determine drive times like those available in google maps

Tags: routing

I'm very new to GIS but have played around a bit with PostGIS and QGIS.

I'm wondering if there's a way to generate drive time estimates like those given by google maps using open-source tools.

For a small number of routes, I can query google maps, and scrape results but I'm sure there's a better way.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating drive time polygons using open source tools](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools)

Comment: Not quite. That question went a different direction I think.

Answer (score 5):

Besides data containing suitable weights (driving time, or length of the road element plus allowed/estimated speed), you'll need a routing tool e.g. pgRouting for PostGIS.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I want to get driving time I don't have it.

Comment: I have a set of starting and ending locations, and PostGIS (therefore pgRouting).  

I gather that pgRouting allows me to find the shortest path between these points, but I need to get the quickest path in terms of travel time, and return the actual travel/drive time.  Similar to the drive time estimate google maps gives.

Comment: If your road network doesn't include information such as speed limits, stop lights/stop signs, turn or direction restrictions,  etc, the calculated travel time will not be that accurate and could be wrong (for instance, if the route goes the wrong way down a one way street).

Comment: @gisnovice: pgRouting can find the path with the shortest length or (if you have the information) with the lowest costs (= travel time). If your graph doesn't contain the necessary info, you can't get good results.

Comment: Seems so much easier to just use Google's API even though it's not 'the right way'.

Out of curiosity, is there a common source for this information for US roadways?  Google has to get the data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

GRASS' v.net.iso (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/html70_user/v.net.iso.html) will also do this.  Again, it takes the right data, and a bit of work to massage it into shape.  However, I have done this successfully in the past, so it does work!  I haven't used pgRouting, but hear it may be a bit more efficient!