# Looking for complicated representations of an urban areas

Tags: qgis

I would like to display some features of an urban area using a map, showing something like telecomunications, roads, or parks, etc. Also, is it possible to get an understanding of how to show more complicated representations of an urban area as I would like to move towards making a more complicated kind of map.

I asked a previous question about this [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46762/i-need-advice-in-using-qgis-lisboa-1-8-vol-2).

Comment: I'm afraid it's not any more intelligible than the other two attempts. Perhaps you could find someone to translate for you?  (Nevertheless, I have reopened this question because it appears that at least one person--thank you, @KevinV!--believes they understand what you are asking.)

Comment: Do you want massive(e.g., with tons of data) urban data, is that it? what do you want to do/test with that? just the display? all qgis capabilities? just to play with the data?

Comment: Sounds like he just wants a complicated map. Try making [isochrones][1] for example. [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools

Comment: All qgis capabilities and to play with a lot of data
A.R.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a good starting place would be to go to the GIS websites for other cities that are of similar populations and look at what types of maps they are distributing.  Then you can see what other groups are doing and get some ideas to start with there.  Then you could apply those ideas to the city you are interested in and maybe come up with a unique combination of your own!

A [google image search for 'Urban GIS'](https://www.google.com/search?q=urban%20GIS&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=u&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS510US510&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=hjjwUMaWGrOA2AWbhYGwBA&ved=0CEgQsAQ&biw=1365&bih=839) seems to have some good starting points.

Comment: well this has been helpful,thank you KevinV.At the moment I am looking at some cool pic from Boston GIS http://www.cityofboston.gov/maps/ ,thank you. I have lack of expirience and imagination with these programs so any help i more than welcome,thanks for undrestading:).