# How to draw a polygon between a number of polygons automatically

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, polygon-creation

The weight “empty” area which is bounded by the orange boundary should represent a land use “Roads” so I should fill it with polygons. Now my question is how to fill these empty areas with polygons automatically?

[image]

I could use Autocomplete Polygons to fill the gaps, but it’s time consuming since I have more than 150 Urban master plans! Is there any method to do this more quickly and more precisely?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know this question has come up a few times before, but strangely I can't find them in searching. There's one for QGIS I found (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70481/) and my answer to a slightly more complicated question for ArcGIS (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93515/) which has some extraneous detail to it. So I'll post a full-standalone answer here.

Comment: Another semi-related question here with some 3rd party extension alternatives to the Erase tool: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103746/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this depending on specific needs and available license level.

First step for all methods is to create a new feature class/layer for the gap areas. Even if you want to have them on the same layer in the end, working with two layers makes things much easier for editing purposes.

Next, draw a generalized polygon on this new temp layer that covers all the areas you wish to fill in. Depending on the method used in the next steps, there are some considerations on how you draw this polygon.

- You could just make a giant polygon that completely surrounds your
  existing ones. With this approach you'll have to do some cutting at
  the end to split your desired areas from the extra surrounding
  leftover (think of cutting out a desired piece from the middle of
  flattened dough).
- You can snap to the vertices where your road meets the outer boundary
  and then use more general, quick placed points within your existing
  polygons to create a generalized shape that covers the roads but doesn't go further than the current outer boundary (so if you have existing ordered
  above temp in the ToC, only the pieces of temp you want are visible).
- You can use [Aggregate Polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000000s000000) (requires Advanced License) to
  create polygons that are the same as the outer boundary of your
  existing polygons (see linked help file for graphic example).

With the temp polygon created, now you need to cut away the parts you don't want using the existing polygons.

- The easiest way is to use the [Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000) tool with temp as the input
  and existing polys as the erase feature, which will eliminate all
  areas in temp covered by existing. However this tool requires an
  Advanced license.
- With only those two layers visible/editable, select all of the
  existing polygons and on the Editor dropdown button choose [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000061000000)
  with a distance of 0 and discard area of intersect.
  **Notes/warnings:** This clip is not the same as the [Clip geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000). Use assumes there is no overlap within the
  existing polygons and no other editable layers are present. This
  method will cut *any and all* visible and editable layers using the
  selected existing polygon outlines.

At this point you should have the road polygons that you want. You may need to use the Cut Polygon tool to trim off excess around the outside depending on how you created the temp polygons, or use the Aggregate Polygons method to create a boundary you can use to clip with. Which of all these variations is fastest depends on your needs and workflow.

Once you have the desired polygons, you can copy and paste, append, or whatever other method you like to get them into your existing polygon layer.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the full description and help. It worked now with me.