# Computing Walking and Cycling Isochrone maps using QGIS & pgRouting?

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

Just installed QGIS as I believe I should be able to produce walking and cycling isochrones from a specified point. I have done this pretty easily before using ArcMap, however, I am really struggling with QGIS.

From what I have read, I should be using PGRouting and OSM2PGrouting mapping (which I have installed). I haven't really used SQL before and seek a dummies guide to doing these isochrones. I have read about various ways, most detailing SQL which I am struggling with.

Comment: http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/12/drive-time-isochrones/ will help get you started

Comment: There are many possible approaches. Pick one and then describe which step you are having trouble with. You will get much more focused answers than by asking for a step-by-step guide for the whole process.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of sources which describe how to develop isochrone maps:

- [Public transport isochrones with pgRouting](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/pgrouting/)

  This post contains information in great detail on how to install, run and conduct a variety of analyses on isochrone maps with pgRouting. Included a couple of images so you can if it's something you are looking for:

[image: pgRouting driving_distance]

Image of *pgRouting driving distance*.

[image: Creating Catchment Areas with pgRouting]

Image of *Catchment Areas with pgRouting*.

- [Creating drive time polygons using open source tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools)

  This post also contains information on how to create drive-time polygons by using the **v.net.iso** tool from **GRASS** which can calculate, for example, the time taken to travel a certain length of road.