# Merging isolines into polygons to produce isochrone map in QGIS

Tags: qgis-2, network, concave-hull, isochrone

**There is** a set of isolines produced with [v.net.iso](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.net.iso.html).

It shows distances in meters [`400`, `800`, `1200`, and everything further] from a certain point.

[image: isochrones]

**My desired output** is an [Isochrone map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochrone_map). However, I do not know yet how to merge/aggregate isolines into polygons, where each isoline located exactly in a proper polygon with no overlaps etc. Better to say I want to draw an outline from the farthest points of each isoline class. What is the best approach?

**I have tried:**

1. extracting nodes from lines `Vector > Geometry Tools > Extract nodes`, filtering with a certain isoline class, and then `Vector > Geometry Tools > Concave Hull`.
2. deploying the QGIS plugin, namely [QGIS-ConcaveHull-Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/concavehull/).

Both outputs are represented on the image below, numbered appropriately. But there is a problem, nodes from the higher-class isoline group overlap the lower-class isoline group. How can I handle this issue?

[image: Output_results]

**I have seen these** articles but nothing spectacular:

- [Drawing outline of point cloud using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189446/drawing-outline-of-point-cloud-using-qgis)
- [Creating drive time polygons using Open Source tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools)
- [Computing Walking and Cycling Isochrone maps using QGIS & pgRouting?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129396/computing-walking-and-cycling-isochrone-maps-using-qgis-pgrouting)
- [How to create contour lines from point data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112890/how-to-create-contour-lines-from-point-data-using-qgis)
- [Create polygon layer from polyline layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30765/create-polygon-layer-from-polyline-layer)

Comment: I think it is necessary to do some interpolations. In the first image, situations are observed in which the union of isochrone points does not produce polygons that only touches. Maybe considering the time as a height, TIN interpolating the points and then extracting contour lines can be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as was specified by @Gabriel De Luca, I required some interpolation as well as contour lines.

After I produced nodes from isolines, I have applied a [QGIS-Contour-Plugin](https://github.com/ccrook/QGIS-Contour-Plugin) which worked much better than any previous solution.

Comment: Nowadays, a very simple way to generate Isochrones as well as Isoareas is the QNEAT3 Plugin. There have been some answers for this that should provide enough information, see e.g. this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381891/88814, this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/378655/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379415/88814